# Optimistic Lock versioned entity with non-versioned many-to-one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on an application with Hibernate 3.5.6.FINAL connected to an Oracle 10g database, and I'm required to prevent dirty reads for particular entities.

To do this, I'm using the JPA's standard Version column. It is configured on our Hibernate XML mappings as follows:

```
<version name="lockVersion" column="LOCK_VERSION"/>
```

But apparently we are now required to use Version on all related entities. 
In particular, we've a many-to-one relationship with another entity `EntityB` which we are not required to cover with version as we do not make inserts or updates on those tables. This relationships are mapped as follows:

```
<many-to-one name="entityB" column="ENTITY_B" class="com.example.EntityB" lazy="false" update="false" insert="false" cascade="none" />
```

The problem is that, whenever we try to make an update on the original entity, we've the following error:

> InvalidDataAccessApiUsage: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

Apparently, Hibernate considers that the instance of `EntityB` is transient as it doesn't have a `Version` (hence, `Version = null`); but it doesn't include a `Version` field because it's unversioned, not because it's transient. Actually, the instance was fetched from the database and it has a Primary Key.

Is there any way to configure Hibernate so it doesn't check that related objects are versioned?

As a note: I'd tried to implement Optimistic Lock with Hibernate non-version mechanism, but our application uses Detached Mode; so this approach is nonviable for us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your entityB got "detached".

In case it is a webapp, the more or less standard way to proceed would be the following.

Let entityA be the entity which has (the nonversioned) entityB as a field (for brevity I don't distinguish classes and objects).

Your web page sends data to update entityA together with entityA's version at the moment that the page was loaded. As soon as the transaction is entered, you load entityA from the database and you compare its current version with the version which arrived from the web page. If the current version is larger (which means newer), you throw an optimistic locking exception. If not, you update the fields of entityA loaded from the database with the data which arrived from the web page (without incrementing the version since it is done automatically), and this is it: as soon as you exit the transaction, the new values of the fields of entityA will be committed - unless some other transaction succeded to update entityA in the database before you, in which case it is Hibernate which throws an optimistic locking related exception.

So if such exceptions are thrown from your transaction, the meaning is "some other transaction already modified the data", and a related message needs to be shown (usually in webapps this message says "The data was modified by another user").

Comment: Oh, maybe it wasn't clear on my original post, but my problem is that the parent entity is loaded from the DB and updated, but Hibernate throws an exception stating EntityB is transient, which is not. EntityB hasn't been modified and shouldn't be updated.

Comment: "..is that the parent entity is loaded from the DB and updated, but Hibernate throws an exception stating EntityB is transient.." - all in the same transaction? If yes, are you modifying somehow the field which contains the reference to entityB?

Comment: Not the same transaction, as we use Detached Mode; but all in the same requests. We receive an ID from the request handler, load the original entity's instance, use the EntityB property to check some dependent fields without altering none of it's values, perform some changes to the original instance and then update the original entity on the database. That's when the error is coming up, stating that EntityB's instance is transient.
I've read that, when `Version` is active, the EntityManager uses it's value to check if all objects are in the persistent context; I need to avoid that for EntityB

Comment: It is the transaction which is important, not the request. If you exit the transaction, your entity becomes "detached", and so is entityB to which it refers. Then when you try to "save or update" your detached entityA, it gives an error since it has a reference to the detached entityB which you do not "save or update". One of your choices might be to load entityB and set the corresponding field of entityA before saving entityA. Since entityB is not to be modified, it can be cached (Hibernate second level cache), thus loading entityB will not harm performance.